# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value - illogical

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, laravel-7

I don't know why I get this error.
My date entry pattern is also correct.
I'm working on Laraval 7 and most of my database tables have been.
why show me this error everything all right ??!!!
[image: PLEASE CHECK THIS SCREEN SHOT]

[image: THIS IS TABLE DETAILS]

Comment: MySQL does not just make errors up because it gets bored! Showus the schema for this table please

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbFj.png

Comment: Are you in a timezone where there will be no `'02:44:10'` because of daylight saving time change?

Comment: @forpas my time zone is +430

Comment: was it +430 at the 2020-03-29? Normally its the 2-3am time hour that is skipped when changes like DST change. This is the likely reason for the error.

Comment: Seems like mysql configuration problem to me , what does mysql error logs says ?

Comment: @Vipertecpro I have no logical error, I was confused myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i've tried

Following is my phpmyadmin setup

[image]

Here is the table schema i've created by looking at the screenshot provided by you:-
[image]

And here is the working query :-
[image]